# Texture Painting Brushes

Tags: texturing, transparency, texture-painting, brushes

I want to add raged holes into demon wings, I'm using an opacity texture with alpha hashed. But the normal texture paint brush leaves mush to soft edges.

What kind of brushes would I need to do general texture painting. And I'm not looking for fancy alpha textures that leave scratch details and so on.

Would a simple round and square brush be enough to do all basic painting

Comment: you can either choose a texture among the procedural Blender textures, like the Cloud one, or import a bitmap image that you'll use as a texture

Answer (score 0):

I think that the key to your main question is to look at manipulation of Falloff in the Brush settings. I here have an example of each of the default falloff curves as brush strokes so that you can see how the edges fare.
[image]

Comment: This is not a solution nor the problem. I think the problem is that vanilla blender just isn't that mature yet texture painting wise. Different brushes(that aren't noise/ detail) are quite important it's like doing a 2d artwork with only 1 brush, it is possible but you won't have a good time or good results.

Comment: Huh, your original question is vague at best, but I tried to interpret what you were asking. I have made plenty of brushes using the existing settings, one of my favorite sets is found here. They might not be what you want but they can help understand what you can do with the procedural textures and mappings. Good luck!! https://blendswap.com/blend/17362